# How to define anonymous function variables in interface Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, interface, react-tsx

I have the next interface in TypeScript:

```
export interface IValue {
    user: string | undefined;
    signin: ({ user, cb }: { user: string | undefined, cb: () => void }) => void;
    signout: (cb: { cb: () => void }) => void;
}
```

In all code places where I use this interface, I need to use the same name variables (`user` and `cb`), for example my AuthProvider.tsx:

```
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';

//Define a default value for Context
const defaultValue: IValue = {
    user: "",
    signin: ()=> {},
    signout: () => {},
}

//create context for keeping username and functions to signin and signout
export const AuthContext = createContext<IValue>(defaultValue);

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: { children: any }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState<string | undefined>();
    //Here I need use `user` and `cb` instead of `newUser` and `callback`
    const signin = ({ user, cb }: { user: string | undefined, cb: () => void }) => {
        setUser(user);
        cb();
    }

    //Here I need use `cb` instead of `callback`
    const signout = ({ cb }: { cb: () => void }) => {
        setUser(undefined);
        cb();
    }

    const value : IValue = { 
        user:user,
        signin:signin,
        signout:signout
    };

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
        {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
}
```

Or Loginpage.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from '../hook/useAuth';

const Loginpage = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const { signin } = useAuth();
    const fromPage = location.state?.from?.pathname || '/';

    const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const user = document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>('input[name="username"]')?.value;
        const cb = ()=>navigate(fromPage, {replace:true});
        //Here I need to wrap `user` and `cb` to call them in signin function
        const t = {user, cb};
        signin(t);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Login page</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Name :<input id='username' name="username" />
                </label>
                <button type="submit">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export { Loginpage }
```

hook in useAuth.ts, because You can see it in Loginpage.tsx

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "../hoc/AuthProvider";

export function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

Can You know there is any opportunity to define interface in this style?

```
export interface IValue {
    user: string | undefined;
    signin: ({ _, _ }: { _: string | undefined, _: () => void }) => void;
    signout: (_: { _: () => void }) => void;
}
```

In jsx I can miss define description `IValue` and get next code:

```
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';

export const AuthContext = createContext(null);

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    const signin = (newUser, cb) => {
        setUser(newUser);
        cb();
    }
    const signout = (cb) => {
        setUser(null);
        cb();
    }

    const value = {user, signin, signout};

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
        {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
}
```

But I want to get more understandable code using Typescript.

Comment: How would you use it then, if the provider and user don't know what the correct keys are?

Comment: Wait... why don't you just use positional parameters/arguments then...?

Comment: Do you mean use:
`const signin = ({ user:newUser, cb:callback  }: { user: string | undefined, cb: () => void }) => {
        setUser(user:newUser);
        cb:callback();
    }
`

In jsx I can miss define description `IValue` and get next code:

Comment: @caTS, I added jsx code in which I can miss interface, code is small, but in all place use type `any`